# require() running unwanted commands from included files

Tags: javascript

When I use require() at the top of my file, it executes the file that I have included. Do I just misunderstand how this function works? Is there a way that I can make it not do this?

thing.js

```
var hello = "helloworld";
var hello2 = "hello2world";

module.exports = {hello, hello2};

console.log(module.exports);
console.log("if this is printing, it's not working");
```

printthing.js

```
var msg = require('./thing.js');

console.log(msg.hello);
```

I just want it to print

```
helloworld
```

But instead I'm getting the output of the first file and helloworld

```
{ hello: 'helloworld', hello2: 'hello2world' }
if this is printing, it's not working
helloworld
```

Comment: Because of the way the language works, when you `import` a module the code in the module all runs, even if you just want access to one exported symbol.

Comment: Just don't put statements directly in your module then; put them inside functions / methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you import `thing.js`, all the lines inside of it are executed. Hence, 
`module.exports` and `"if this is printing, it's not working"` are printed first, and, after those, `msg.hello` is printed.